# LightGBMのインストールがうまくいきません

Tags: python, kaggle

Kaggle初心者です
stackoverflowも初めての利用なので至らないところが多いと思いますがお許しください。
LightGBMのインストールがうまくいきません、、、
公式の手順に沿ってインストールしたのですが、

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

のように、`import lightgbm as lgb` で `ImportError: cannot import name 'zip_'` というエラーが出てしまいます。

どなたか、わかるかたいらっしゃいましたら教えてください。よろしくお願いします。
Apple Clangとgccを試しました。

#### 追記

- 環境

  - mac OS High Sierra バージョン10.13.6
  - Python 3.6.3 :: Anaconda, Inc.
- インストールは以下のドキュメントにしたがって行いました。Python-package のインストールは `brew install libomp` して `pip install wheel pip install lightgbm` することにより行いました。

  - https://github.com/Microsoft/LightGBM/blob/master/docs/Installation-Guide.rst
- https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/lightgbm からanacondaでのインストールも試したのですが、

  [image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

  インストールの途中で上の写真のようなエラーが発生してしまいます。
- コメントでご指摘いただいたように `compat.py` の内容をgithubのものとローカルの `~/.pyenv/versions/anaconda3-5.0.1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/lightgbm/compat.py` で比較してみましたが、同一でした。

  [image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: [ここ](https://github.com/Microsoft/LightGBM/blob/master/python-package/lightgbm/compat.py#L15)を見ますと、Python3 の場合は zip_ == zip になっています。~/.pyenv/versions/anaconda3-5.0.1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/lightgbm/compat.py ファイルの内容が GitHub 上の compat.py と同一かどうかを確認してみて下さい。

Comment: nekketsuuuさん、 metropolis さんありがとうございます。

Comment: @ryopal さん、スクリーンショットだとググラビリティが落ちるので、見た目の情報を伝えたいときでない限りはテキストをコピー＆ペーストして頂けるとありがたいです。

Comment: LightGBM の python-package はどのようにインストールなさったのか追記して頂けませんでしょうか？　[リンク頂いている Installation Guide](https://github.com/Microsoft/LightGBM/blob/master/docs/Installation-Guide.rst) には LightGBM CLI のインストール方法までしか書かれておらず、python-package のインストール方法は[別になっています](https://github.com/Microsoft/LightGBM/tree/master/python-package)。

Comment: @ nekketsuuuさんご指摘ありがとうございます。次回から気をつけます。
brew install libomp
pip install wheel
pip install lightgbm
の手順で行いました。

Answer (score 1):

`import lightgbm as lgb`で`ImportError: cannot import name 'zip_'`というエラーが出るということですが、`LightGBM`のコードを見ても通常そのようなエラーが発生することはありません。

`LightGBM`をコンパイルやインストールしてみましたが問題が発生することはないし、GitHubのIssuにも`Clang`及び`gcc`のバージョンの問題以外にこのようなエラーが発生しているケースはありません。

また、pyenv+anacondaというのは便利かもしれませんが、その仕様上 anacondaでpipを使ったり、最新のバージョンのcondaを使う時には問題が発生しやすいという特徴があります。

こういうことから考えれば、再度インストールをやり直すのが早いと思います。

なお、`LightGBM`はPyPIにバイナリー版も公開されているので、公式Pythonを使うのであれば、以下で、

```
pip3 install numpy scipy scikit-learn lightgbm
```

Anaconda であれば、

```
conda install -c conda-forge lightgbm
```

で、数分でインストールできます。

Comment: @nekketsuuuさん色々ありがとうございました。助かりました。
@Yasuhiro Nijiさんありがとうございます。うまくいきました！